# Errors during linking GLFW files

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, g++

I have built GLFW from source and trying to build applications with it on Ubuntu Linux. But, `g++` is always throwing errors about undefined references. I have followed many sites and posts, but they didn't solve my problem. This is my code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

using namespace glm;

int main() {
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 01", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental=true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this program with this command: `g++ glfw_prog.cpp -lGL -lglfw3 -o glfw_prog`.

But, I am getting this long error https://pastebin.com/1b8fB2h7.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please, do NOT use screenshots of error messages. Instead, paste the error message with a proper formatting (as a code). See also [ask].

Comment: The link that I provided is not of any screenshot. It's a text which shows the error. I couldn't paste it here because it had crossed the word limit.

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is not a screenshot. Still, the error message should be pasted directly to the question post. If your log is too long, then show only the first error message, or several first messages. If you think that full log would also be useful, you may also provide the link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed [this](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html#build_link_pkgconfig) site and solved my problem. I had to use the command `gcc -o glfw_prog glfw_prog.cpp $(pkg-config --static --libs glfw3) -lGLEW`. I just had to add the extra `-lGLEW` flag along with the pkg-config search path.

More specifically, this is the complete and system-independent command:
`gcc -o glfw_prog glfw_prog.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lglfw3 -lrt -lm -ldl -lX11 -lpthread -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp -lGLEW -lGL`

Answer (score 0):

I got your program to compile with the following flags on Ubuntu:

```
g++ glfw_prog.cpp -lGL -lglfw -lGLEW -o glfw_prog
```

Comment: I have `glfw3` instead of `glfw`. When I used the switch `-lGLEW`, I get this error: 
 `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(vulkan.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`